# React Add filtering on pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a product page sorted by title. Sorting works, everything is fine, but when pagination occurs, new items are loaded without sorting. How to fix it?

```
const Grid = ({filter, countOnRow, totalCount, products}) => {
const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true)
const [total, setTotal] = useState(totalCount)
const [startPage, setStartPage] = useState(0)
const [produs, setProdus] = useState([])
const [okay, setOkay] = useState(false)
const [selectedSort, setSelectedSort] = useState('')

useEffect(()=>{
    if(fetching){
        setProdus([...produs, ...products.slice(startPage,total)])
        setStartPage(total)
        setTotal(total+total)
        setFetching(false )

    }
}, [fetching])

useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHadnler);

    return function(){
        document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHadnler)
    };
}, [])

const scrollHadnler=(e)=>{
    if(e.target.documentElement.scrollHeight-(e.target.documentElement.scrollTop+window.innerHeight)<100){
        setFetching(true)
        
    }
}
const sortByName = (sort) => {
    setSelectedSort(sort)
    setProdus([...produs].sort((a,b) => a[sort].localeCompare(b[sort])))
    setOkay(!okay)
}
```

How can I implement the filtering to persist after pagination.

Comment: Where is sortByName actually used?

Comment: Follow this step, create a `useEffect()` and its dependency will be the data array, and under this effect process the data and sort and use that data to show in table. By this was every time new data is fetched the effect will sort the data and show it in right format